# Unable to use SDK Manager in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to do anything in the SDK Manager. I updated the Android Studio and the Standalone SDK Manager is deprecated i know that. But I am unable to use the one that is currently there. I cant click or select anything not even show package details. Applications that i already have are working fine, I am also able to make new applications but on API 24. How do i update the SDK and use this Manager?

[image]

Comment: can you try put SDK somewhere else? Like some C:\android\sdk etc? Does that work?

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't Help.

Comment: Never mind, I reinstalled the whole Studio and it seems to work now.